# Dynamically add component to child routes of imported library

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, angular-routing, angular-module

I'm looking for a way to execute such case:

- In one Angular workspace there are two projects - one a library project with components and second *main* project that uses the components from that library;
- The Library consists of a Settings module that has a menu on the left and *view* on the right, where *router-outlet* for Settings module *child routes* is used;
- Settings Module enables the user to configure the module in a way, that the menu contains an option to click with bound component - after clicking an option, the component is shown on the right and option highlighted;

```js
export const config = {
  authorization: {},
  navigation: {
    title: 'Test page',
    homeRoute: 'home',
    actions: [{ title: 'Do stuff', route: '/settings' }]
  },
  settings: {
    groups: [
      {
        groupName: 'Advanced',
        options: [
          {
            name: 'Settings Option Route',
            route: 'test',
            component: TestComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, TestComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ThatImportedLibrary['forRoot'](config)
   ],
  exports: [TestComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Settings component in Library takes out the data about routes in the injected object and resets children routes based on it (by using main *settings* route and adding child component from the **config object**).

```js
export const settingsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'settings',
    component: SettingsPanelComponent,
    children: []
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(settingsRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SettingsPanelRoutingModule {
  constructor(@Inject(ConfigService) private config: FacConfig) {
    // RouterModule.forChild(settingsRoutes);
    // Looking for a way to dynamically add the child route from config object
    const settingsRoutes = [
      {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsPanelComponent,
        children: []
      }
    ];

    const childRoute = {
        path: config.settings.groups[0].options[0].route
        component: config.settings.groups[0].options[0].component
    }

    settingsRoutes[0].children.push(childRoute);
    this.router.resetConfig(settingsRoutes);
    }
}
```

It does not work, however - after clicking the option with child component from the main module (TestComponent) it causes:

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for TestComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? at noComponentFactoryError (component_factory_resolver.ts:17)
```

- In the main project, after importing the library, it is possible to go to route */settings* which opens the menu with options;
- The options in Settings are provided with a name, route path, and component **that exists in main project**;
- Clicking on an option should open up assigned route e.g. */settings/test*, but it does not work (look above);
- **Is it possible to reference external component (from the different app) as a child route to the imported module?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I answered it myself - in the main app.module I just needed to add that specific module to *entryComponents* property in @NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, TestComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ThatImportedLibrary["forRoot"](config)
  ],
  exports: [TestComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [TestComponent] // that's all!
})
```